# How to run a method using scheduler after the flask app has started

Tags: python, flask, scheduled-tasks, apscheduler

```
@app.route('/page1', methods = ['POST'])
def func1():
    pass

@app.route('/page2', methods = ['POST'])
def func2():
    pass

def func3():
    pass

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=xxxx,debug=True)
```

How do I schedule run func3() so that it gets triggered after the flask app has started?

I have used python schedule, Flask-APScheduler, APScheduler...the method is running every interval but how do I trigger it after the flask app has started?

Comment: Does the app have to be fully loaded, or is it only about running some code after `app.run` has been called?

Answer (score 0):

After the : place your scheduler.

`if __name__ == '__main__': 
    scheduler.func3()

    app.run('localhost', 5000, debug=True)`

You'll need to declare how often you would like the scheduler to function, however, so you can write it likes this:

```
    scheduler.add_job(id='Third Function', func=func3, trigger="interval", seconds=40000)
```